# Como usar o require/include dentro do laço de repetição?

Tags: loop, include

Qual é a maneira mais adequada de retornar o conteúdo dinâmico de um script PHP,  carregado via include dentro de um laço de repetição?
Segue abaixo mais detalhes:

pagina1.php -> retorna o nome das empresas cadastradas em um banco de dados

pagina.php2 -> retorna as informações de cada empresa conforme o ID repassado para a página.

```
for  {
  $codigo_empresa = $registro['empresa_codigo'];
  $empresa = $registro['empresa_nome'];
  include pagina2.php
}
```

O problema é que o conteúdo retornado da página2.php é sempre o mesmo, ou seja, ele faz o include uma única vez e durante o laço de repetição, apenas repete o valor retornado do primeiro registro.

Detalhe: preciso fazer o retorno via include, pois esta página é utilizada em outras partes do sistema.

Fiz o teste com include e require e todos eles retornam o mesmo resultado.

Comment: ao invés de usar include pq não usa GET e passa a variavel?

Comment: Então, na verdade utilizo o include para buscar um codigo HTML e diversos outros dados de cada empresa, e assim utilizo o Loop para fazer o envio de mensagens em massa. Quando eu fazia o envio de maneira avulsa, funcionava perfeitamente, e agora que estou tentando fazer o envio em massa, estou me defrontando com este detalhe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> O problema é que o conteúdo retornado da página2.php é sempre o mesmo,

De um único include fora do loop, já que o valor retornado é sempre o mesmo.

Para que vc vai redeclarar a mesma coisa múltiplas vezes com o mesmo valor?

> Então, na verdade utilizo o include para buscar um codigo HTML e diversos outros dados de cada empresa, e assim utilizo o Loop para fazer o envio de mensagens em massa.

Imagino por esse comentário, que não é exatamente igual. Vc deve estar fazendo algo como "Ola, João, Nos da empresa ABCD...." e no outro "Ola, João, Nos da empresa XPTO...."

Se na pagina2.php tem algum resultado que fica diferente baseado no $codigo_empresa ou $codigo, transforme o código do pagina2.php em classe e trabalhe com objetos.

Assim fica muito mais claro e lógico o que o seu código está fazendo.

Algo do tipo:

```
include pagina2.php
for {
  $codigo_empresa = $registro['empresa_codigo'];
  $emp = new Empresa($codigo_empresa);
  $empresa_nome = emp->getNome();
  $empresa_endereco = emp->getEnd();
  $ok = emp->enviaEmail('João','joao@email.com');
  if ( $ok !== true ) {
     echo "Erro no envio do email da empresa:" . $empresa_nome;
  }
}
```

Se tiver mais detalhes do código podemos ajudar melhor.